# Passing JSON array from jsp to javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I've searched for two days now and tried every possible thing I think.
I use GSON to create a JSON array.  When I print out my json string before sending it to Javascript via jquery it looks like this:

```
[{"var1":"hi","var2":"this","var3":"is"}]
```

Looks good to me.  I've tried sending to js the following 2 ways:

```
String json = gson.toJson(googData, listType);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

and

```
String json = gson.toJson(googData, listType);
<%= json %>
```

Here's my js code:

```
$.getJSON("testgoogle.jsp", function(json) {
    $.each (json, function(k, v) {
        alert(v.val1);
    });
});
```

Pretty simple right?  I can change it to $.get and see the string.  If I alert(k) it only alerts 0 one time.  I have a suspicion that i'm passing some white space with my json string.  When I alert anything returned from the jsp's it appears lower in the alert box than say an alert("hi").  You know where the ! is in the alert box and how "hi" is right in the middle of the ! img.  Well when I have <%= "hi" %> sent from jsp it is below the !.  I moved <%= "hi" %> all the way to the top so my jsp looked like:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%= "hi" %>
```

As you can see, I'm grasping at straws. This returned "hi" at the bottom of the !.  The more lines in my jsp I move the "hi" down the lower it is in my alert box. Also, something weird.  If I leave this at the top of my jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

That will actually print out in my alert.

Please let me know if you need more info.

**Solution:**
I was trying to call val1 when the key was var1.  Wow! I will never get all those hours back ;)  The correct code is identical to the above except val1 should be var1.  Also, I tried it with eval(json) and it still worked FYI. Thanks for trying to help everyone!

Comment: as a sidenote, why do you do this from inside a JSP?  The former code is identical to what you'd use in a servlet, which would a) be a lot cleaner and b) you wouldn't have to worry about things like white space generated by JSP directives & co.

Comment: I guess I just never thought to try. Are you talking about not using JQuery?

Comment: not at all, just suggesting you replace your server side JSON generating JSP by a plain servlet.  JSPs are a view technology, there's not a lot to view here :-)

Comment: ouch, that sounds very painful - not familiar with WAS7, doesn't it support redeployment of wars?

Comment: Can i ask what the js would look like? I've mostly done Java programs and other scripting. What would the callback look like? $.getJSON("url_to_servlet".....?

Comment: indeed - and the code fragment you showed above (response etc) would also what's needed in the body of the servlets doGet / processRequest method

Comment: @fvu one more question. I would like to leave the code here for anyone that might find it useful. However, much of my post is irrelevant. Should edit it out or just leave it?  Also, I'm using a servlet. Thanks for the advise!

Comment: just leave it like it is, otherwise the comments (over which you have no control) will make no more sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

[$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/)

> The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a
>   JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed
>   using the $.parseJSON() method. It is also passed the text status of
>   the response.

You don't have to "parse" the string yourself as it is already parsed by jQuery

```
$.getJSON("testgoogle.jsp", function(json) {
    $.each (json, function(k, v) {
        alert(v.val1);
    });
});
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you changed here? I tried this:
    $.getJSON("testgoogle.jsp", function(json) { alert(json.val1)
It's undefined

Comment: I've removed the 'eval(...)' as you've done it yourself. 'json' is an array so you'll have to use 'json[0].val1' if you're not going to use $.each anymore

Answer (score 0):

In $.getJSON the `json` in `function(json) {` is alraedy a JavaScript object so you don't eval it

Comment: Yea. I tried that. I've tried 100's of variations of the js syntax it seems. I even tried $.makeArray and $.map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.getJSON("testgoogle.jsp", function(json) {
$.each (json[0], function(k, v) {
    alert(v);
    });
});
```